# How to clone background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have this picture, where I would like to fill out the green in the top with the background from the picture, so fix that the picture have not been cropped in 4:3.

Can a background like this be cloned?

[image]

Comment: I'm all for asking basic questions... but erm.. what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Photoshop's CS6 (also available in CS5) content aware feature.

**Select the part** you want to fill with the selection tool.

**Shift+Backspace** to launch the fill dialog.

Make sure "Content-Aware" is selected under the "Use" part, and you're done.

Tip: To get an even better result, you could use content-aware on the thin line that separates the original background, and the one created using the content aware tool.

**EDIT**: 
Added some photos as example [here](http://www.shahardekel.co.il/photoshop-stuff/photoshop-content-aware-1.html)

Comment: Very good answer and nice example.